# join/union while summing columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having an issue when an entry doesn't exist in one of the tables I'm joining.

Setup is like this:

(This table contains list of people who can put people on a free-entry list)

Table 1:

```
ID,NAME,GUESTS
```

where `GUESTS` is how many they let in without a name in the following list:

(This contains the names and guests of all people who were granted free entry)

Table 2:

```
ID,PROMOTERID,NAME,GUESTS
```

where `PROMOTERID` is a foreign key to Table 1 colum ID.

The idea is that whatever is in the `GUESTS` field in Table 1 should be added to the total guests that this promoter has put on the list in Table 2. e.g., if Promoter with ID 4 has put 6 people on the free entry list, but also let an additional 3 people in (which would be stored in his `GUESTS` value in table 1), I need a view where Promoter ID has a total guest count of 9.

This works as long as the promoter HAS a value in table 2. If his ID cannot be found in table 2 - that is, if he let someone in for free but never put someone on the free entry list, he isn't included in the view.

View looks like:

```
select `table1`.`NAME` AS `NAME`,`table2`.`PROMOTERID` AS `Promoter`
,(sum(`table2`.`GUESTS`) + `table1`.`GUESTS`) AS `TOTAL` from
(`table1` join `table2` on((`table1`.`ID` = `table2`.`PROMOTERID`))),
group by `table2`.`PROMOTERID`
```

What do I need to change to get the total regardless of the presence of an entry for a given promoter ID in table 2?

Comment: Left join will bring back columns where there is a null

Comment: I tried using left join, but that puts NULL in the field. I don't need null. In case the promoter has nobody in table2, I need his count from table 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `LEFT JOIN` in combination with `IFNULL` to get what you want:

```
select `table1`.`NAME` AS `NAME`,`table2`.`PROMOTERID` AS `Promoter`
,(IFNULL(sum(`table2`.`GUESTS`),0) + `table1`.`GUESTS`) AS `TOTAL` from
(`table1` LEFT join `table2` on((`table1`.`ID` = `table2`.`PROMOTERID`))),
group by `table1`.`ID`
```

This will give 0 (zero) if table2 doesn't have any records related to table1, and therefore the addition will work as you want it to work.

A description of `IFNULL` can be found here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html

Comment: This gives the same issue as COALESCE. If more than one person has something in his COUNT field but does not have an entry in table2 with his ID, only the first found of these promoters will show in your solution.

Comment: Ah, I overlooked that the grouping in the query is on table2. Doesn't it help if you change the grouping to `group by table1.id`?

Comment: Nope, still only get one result where I should be getting two (or more).

Comment: Hold the phone - now suddenly it works! I get two rows with NULL in promoterID (i actually dont even need this column as the ID is irrelevant in this case, I just need their grand total) but with correct values in the GUESTS column.
Thanks!

Comment: I'll edit my original answer to reflect my previous comment, so you can accept the actual answer :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking for the grand total of people let in by promoters it would be.

```
SELECT SUM(t.Guests)
FROM Table1 AS t
```

Comment: This only gives the total if they let someone in but doesn't include their guest list entries.